# Were Dana and Louis picked explicitly?

Tags: ghostbusters

Dana and Louis are the two characters possessed in the Ghostbusters film. Dana Barrett's appartment seems to be 'spook central', which is the only reason she was picked, correct?

Under what criteria was Louis Tully picked? Proximity, attachment/relationship to Dana, personnality?

Comment: Are you seeking in-universe reasons?

Comment: Have you seen the [Wiki page for him](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Louis_Tully)?  Is there anything not answered there?

Comment: I find the wiki page vague on whether either were picked out or just picked. Louis' dog could have appeared and chased any of the guests. But Louis has/had feelings for Dana who was, I think 'marked' for possession. I want to know if these things are related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is any criteria besides proximity to where the hellhounds spawned, which is of course speculation, it would be gender.

Since it seemed Gozer was only spawned after the Keymaster and the Gatekeeper found one another, the audience is left to assume that some Demon-spawning mating ritual took place on the roof.

Would this same ritual have worked if the hounds possessed 2 humans of the same gender? 
*There is nothing in Ghostbusters lore to support speculation either way*.

Comment: Thank you for expanding on 'no'. Much nicer than plain 'no'.